# How to download magento community edition

Tags: magento

I am using this url to download the magento. I registered and login but nothing happening. Every time on download it shows me login popup.

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
```

Please help to let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is apparently a local browser issue as I was able to log in, go to the downloads page, choose and be presented with the download popup.

If the downloads page is not working for you, you can always try the direct assets link with either a web browser or wget. For example, to get Magento 1.9.0.1:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.1/magento-1.9.0.1.tar.gz

And if you know the version and file name, you should be able to work out the file URL for other versions.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to download Magento (at least v2+) without going via gated email signup is:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and able to download by using following URL :-
http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/

I am using Firefox & Chrome.